# Loop list in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, loops, for-loop

I have a main page where there are links to 5 other pages with the following xpaths from tr[1] to tr[5].

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div[1]/a
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/div[1]/a
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/div[1]/a
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/div[1]/a
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/div[1]/a
```

Inside every page there I have the following actions:

```
driver.find_element_by_name('key').send_keys('test_1')

driver.find_element_by_name('i18n[en_EN][value]').send_keys('Test 1')

# and at the end this takes me back to the main page again
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/ul/li[2]/a').click()
```

How can I iterate so that the script will go through all 5 pages and do the above actions. Tried for loop but I guess I didn't do it right... any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: what did you try? share some code

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
xpath = '/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[3]/div[1]/a'

for i in range(1, 6):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath.format(i)).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

seems like I figured it out so here is the answer which works for me now.

```
wls = ['/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div[1]/a',
       '/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/div[1]/a',
       '/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/div[1]/a',
       '/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/div[1]/a',
       '/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/div[1]/a']

for i in wls:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(i).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

below

```
template = '/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[3]/div[1]/a'
for x in range(1,6):
    a = template.format(x)
    print(a)
    # do what you need to do with the 'a' element.
```

output

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div[1]/a
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/div[1]/a
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/div[1]/a
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/div[1]/a
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/div[1]/a
```